# Какой тип нейронной сети нужно выбрать для решения задачи?

Tags: нейронные-сети

У меня имеется набор изображений с коррозионными дефектами, на основе которых я хочу научить НС обводить дефекты контурами.

На вход дается левое изображение, на выходе - правое.

[image: дефекты с контуром и без]

Какой тип нейронной сети мне следует выбрать для решения этой задачи?

Альтернативные варианты решения также приветствуются. Найти качественный способ выделения не смог.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте использовать [Semantic Segmentation CNN](https://github.com/GeorgeSeif/Semantic-Segmentation-Suite):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

PS вам придется обучить НС на ваших данных